# como passar duas variáveis PHP na função onclick do botão html?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```
echo '<button onclick="deleteVaga('.$id,$cidade.')"><i class="far fa-trash-alt" style="font-size:36px;color:#f00;"></i></button>';
```

na função deleteVaga, ele reconhece só uma variável passada, mas não sei como passar $id e $cidade como dois parâmetros, para depois buscar com ajax.

Comment: `echo '<button onclick="deleteVaga('.$id,$cidade.')"><i class="far fa-trash-alt" style="font-size:36px;color:#f00;"></i></button>';` Altera para `echo '<button onclick="deleteVaga('.$id.','.$cidade.')"><i class="far fa-trash-alt" style="font-size:36px;color:#f00;"></i></button>';` A vírgula faz parte do html e não do php que está sendo passado.

Comment: Já tentei assim também e não funcionou, existe outra forma de passar esses parâmetros?

Comment: Não campeão, uma resolução da sua pergunta. No evento `deleteVaga` vc está passando a vírgula sem encapsular para ser identificada como um html, portanto, apenas inseri um `deleteVaga('.$id.','.$cidade.')`. Veja agora que a vírgula faz parte do html .

Comment: Como a cidade provavelmente tem espaço, você precisa que ela esteja dentro de aspas, desse jeito `('.$id.',\''.$cidade.'\')`

Comment: Perfeito Dobrychtop, funcionou exatamente como eu queria, como eu fecho ou dou essa pergunta como solucionada?